# How to get TFS 2017 Current Iteration using SSRS (SQL Server reporting Services)

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, azure-devops, ssrs-2012

I am working on a SSRS report for TFS 2017 Update 3 on-prem. It's extracting data for a specific IterationPath, given as a parameter. 
I  would like to set the Parameter's default value to the current iteration. 
I thought it should be simple, but I am googling and trying resolutions for a while now, and nothing... would be happy to hear if anyone managed to solve this.

One of the leads I found, was to use tbl_nodes in the collection DB, but it is empty on my DB. Another solution, which must have worked in tehthe past, but no longer does, is: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/yuvmaz/2012/10/17/tfs-reporting-recipes-1-get-the-iteration-pathguid-for-the-current-sprint/

Comment: Can you use the REST api?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by browsing the TFS DB and running queries. there is very little documentation, unfortunately.

Here is the solution that works for me:

Connect to the warehouse DB and run this query (I added a check of iteration path to narrow down the results to the ones that suite my requirement):

```
SELECT        IterationPath
FROM            DimIteration
WHERE        (IterationPath LIKE '\XX\Y%Z%') AND (CONVERT(date, FinishDate) >= CONVERT(date, GETDATE())) AND (CONVERT(date, StartDate) <= CONVERT(date, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: It's worth noting that directly querying the TFS project collection databases is **unsupported** and is not recommended. The analysis and warehouse databases are intended for querying, nothing else.